# Create separate template for shared custom taxonomy with shared terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

[image]I have created custom taxonomy called "product_category", it has been shared with post type "books" and "movies" .

So I need to create a different template for both post types.

Both the templates' design will be different, so its important that both the post_type shared taxonomy (even their terms will be shared in both the post_type.) should have different template .

Path should be like :-

> site/books/product_category/horror/
>
> site/movies/product_category/horror/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, It's quite difficult to have path like

> site/books/product_category/horror/
>
> site/movies/product_category/horror/

As wordpress functionality will conflict between custom_post_type & their taxonomy if try to keep url like you mentioned. I suggest you consider the I mentioned below as a solution of your problem.

> site/product_category/horror/?post_type=books
>
> site/product_category/horror/?post_type=movies

Now to keep template as per shared terms, Create two templates in your theme directory.

- common-term-books.php
- common-term-movies.php

And, use this code to redirect to template on the basis of custom post type:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_152146_template_override', 99 );
function wpse_152146_template_override(){
    if (is_tax()) {
        if ( 'books' == $_GET['post_type']) {

            $new_template = locate_template( array( 'common-term-books.php' ) );
            if ( '' != $new_template ) {
                return $new_template ;
            }

        }
        elseif ( 'movies' == $_GET['post_type']) {

            $new_template = locate_template( array( 'common-term-movies.php' ) );
            if ( '' != $new_template ) {
                return $new_template ;
            }

        }
        else
            return $template;
    }
    else
        return $template;
}
```

Additionally, You can also use custom_term_link function i created to get url on the basis of post_type

```
function get_custom_term_link( $term, $taxonomy, $post_type ){
    $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
    return $link.'?post_type='.$post_type;
}

get_custom_term_link( 'horror', 'product_category', 'books');
```

Don't forget to create template file ***common-term-books.php*** & ***common-term-movies.php***. Otherwise, it'll just show blank white screen.

Comment: hi your code work perfectly, but if any one try;s to open URL normaly like "site/product_category/horror/" its give a blank page. i tried to add taxonomy template but it doesn't work.

Comment: It should work if you've created taxonomy page. Refer: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: the custom_term_link function breaks if there is no post available in the following term. and i need the link even if the term is empty. please Improve this function.