# Query only current post type using taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have several post types "Courses", "Institutes" having same taxonomy "country". I am using this to get term on single-courses.php

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'country' ); 
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'country' );
    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
    continue;
    echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
} 
?>
```

When I click term, it get all post types having "country" taxonomy. How can I use it to get ONLY CURRENT POST TYPE.

Comment: Have a look at this answer [Create separate template for shared custom taxonomy with shared terms](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152146/create-separate-template-for-shared-custom-taxonomy-with-shared-terms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you look at WordPress' available query variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables), you will notice `post_type`. You will need to add that to your URL:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'category' ); 
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'category' );
  if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) 
  continue;
  $term_link = add_query_arg(
    array(
      'post_type' => $post->post_type
    ),
    $term_link
  );
  echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<?php
$post_type = 'your_current_post_type_name';
$tax = 'your_taxonomy_name';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax);
if ($tax_terms) {
  foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => $post_type, // Here you will tell Wordpress only query on this post type
      "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            ...
        <?php
      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
  }
}
?>
```

Using `var_dump($tax_term)` you can verify exactly what is available to use (name, slug, ID, count, etc) - if everything run as expected, all these attributes should be available to use:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] =>
    [name] =>
    [slug] =>
    [term_group] => 
    [term_order] => 
    [term_taxonomy_id] =>
    [taxonomy] =>
    [description] => 
    [parent] =>
    [count] =>
    [object_id] =>
)
```